# Como converter uma String para TNotifyEvent no Delphi?

Tags: delphi, string, variáveis, pascal, object-pascal

Quero mudar o evento OnTimer de um TTimer no meu projeto em tempo de execução, tentei da seguinte forma: `Timer1.OnTimer:= ('close');` Mas o Delphi informa isto: `(E2010 Incompatible types: 'TNotifyEvent' and 'string')`, como poderei converter a String `'Close'` para `TNotifyEvent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para usar um arquivo .INI;
Primeiro criar um arquivo do tipo .ini com o conteúdo exemplo:

[P_LOG]

comando = teste

Função para fazer a leitura do arquivo .ini:

```html
function TForm1.LeIni(sIndice, sCampo: string): string;
var
  ArqIni: TIniFile;
begin
  try
    Result := '';
    ArqIni := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) +'Teste.ini');
    try
    Result := Trim(ArqIni.ReadString(sIndice, sCampo, ''));
    finally
    ArqIni.Free;
    end;
  except
    ShowMessage
    ('Não foi possível encontrar o arquivo de Parâmetros .ini');
  end;

end;
```

Usando a função

```html
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
  ConteudoArquivoINI :String;
begin
 ConteudoArquivoINI := LeIni('P_LOG', 'comando')) the
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Você deve enviar uma Procedure para o Ontimer, e não uma String.
Se sua intenção com a String 'Close' for fechar o Formulario é simples, crie uma Procedure com o tipo (Sender: TObject) com o comando Close:

```
procedure FecharFormulario(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;
```

Para o Evento OnTimer você faz:

```
Timer1.OnTimer := FecharFormulario;
```

Comment: E se eu quiser dar a função do evento através de parâmetros estabelecidos por um arquivo INI?

Comment: Ai voltamos a estaca Zero, onde você não deve enviar String para o Evento!

Answer (score 0):

Dá pra fazer algo como criar um record para armazenar o nome de cada procedimento:

`type
  mrec = record
    nome: string;
    proc: procedure(Sender: TObject) of Object;
  end;
...
var
  s : string;
  procs: array of mrec;
begin
  Setlength(procs, 2);
  procs[0].nome := 'Button8Click';
  procs[0].proc := Button8Click;
  procs[1].nome := 'Button6Click';
  procs[1].proc := Button6Click;
end;
...
procedure ExecutaPeloNome(nome: string);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to length(procs) - 1 do
    if procs[i].nome = nome then
    begin
      procs[i].proc(nil);
      break;
    end;
end;
...
ExecutaPeloNome('Button8Click');`

Honestamente, não acho que vale a pena!

Comment: essa linha: proc: procedure(Sender: TObject) of Object; pode ser: proc: TNotifyEvent;